# How do i add avoid point when call direction API in android map

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I currently building a google map app direction to avoid traffic jam point or something like that. I would like to ask is there a way for me to do my idea. I really need your help. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like a following feature request:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35816642

As you can see, currently there is no option to avoid a waypoint in the Directions API. You can only specify waypoints to include in the route, but not the opposite.

Feel free to star a feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.